Why does the presense of "graphql`" in a *.tsx file cause a vite internal server error Unexpected token, expected "from"
I'm using vite@5.2.0 with react@18.2.0 and react-relay@16.2.0. I'm following the tutorial on https://relay.dev/docs/tutorial/fragments-1/.
The file that causes the internal server error, HelloWorld.tsx contains:
const GraphQLHelloWorldQuery = graphql`
  query GraphQLHelloWorldQuery {
    fetchFruit(id: 1) {
        color
    }
  }
`;

export function HelloWorld() {
    const data = useLazyLoadQuery<GraphQLHelloWorldQueryType>(GraphQLHelloWorldQuery, {});
    console.log(data);
    
    return <div>Hello GraphQL</div>;
}


The error logged is:
[vite] Internal server error: /.../src/GraphQLHelloWorld/HelloWorld.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "from" (4:12)

  2 | import { graphql } from 'relay-runtime';
  3 | import { useLazyLoadQuery } from "react-relay";
> 4 | import type { GraphQLHelloWorldQuery as GraphQLHelloWorldQueryType  } from "./__generated__/GraphQLHelloWorldQuery.graphql";

I can get rid of the above error by deleting (commenting out won't work) the code containing "graphql`".
It looks like "graphql..." isn't parsed correctly.
I'm not sure this is enough information to help.
Any pointers in the right direction are most welcome.
Update 1)
I re-initialized Vite with Typescript and without SWC and the above error disappeared. So react-swc-ts is problematic while react-ts is fine.

import type, { GraphQLHelloWorldQuery..., not import type { GraphQLHelloWorldQuery....

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I believe that's valid: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Looks like it, but I don't see mention of the ESM as keyword, try without that?

Is this the full file content? What about the imports of graphql and useLazyQuery? The error seems to be in the import section, why leave out the imports?

Thanks for the comments so far. The error location is misleading and the import statement is not the problem. What I have learnt after posting this question, is that the error disappears when Vite is used with Typescript instead of SWC. So react-swc-ts is problematic while react-ts is fine.
